# C# replace double quotes with single quote

Tags: c#

I have a string that has two sets of double double quotes as below:

```
string ns = @"<tns:Event xmlns:tns=""http://sbr.gov.au/comn/event.02.data"">";
```

I need to replace the two sets of double double quotes around the namespace with a single quote but I'm struggling to see how to do it. I'm sure this is pretty easy but I'm pretty new to C#.

Thanks in advance.

Just to expand on my wider issue a little. Below is the code I'm using within an SSIS script component:

```
string xml = Row.RejectReason.ToString();
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XNamespace tns = "http://sbr.gov.au/comn/event.02.data";
var eventItems = xDoc.Element(tns + "Event").Element(tns + "EventItems").Elements(tns + "EventItem");
foreach (var eventItem in eventItems)
{
   Row.RejectReason = eventItem.Element(tns + "Short.Description").Value;
}
```

The Parsing of the XML is failing due to the the double double quotes around the namespace within the XML. That XML fragment is coming from a CSV file.

Comment: Those are only one double quote. When you have a string literal with an `@` sign, that's how a double quote is escaped.

Comment: _"I need to replace the two sets of double double quotes around the namespace with a single quote"_  - Is it only me, or OP wants to replace `"` (double quotes)  with `'` (single quote)?

Comment: I should probably have included more detail as the literal above was just to show the string. As part of an SSIS package I'm working on I have a string presented with the two sets of double double quotes so I cannot parse the XML. I need to modify the string on the fly with a script task to insert single quotes instead. So my namespace will look like:

'http://sbr.gov.au/comn/event.02.data'

Comment: @C.Spice So, did you checked any of answers?

Comment: @SeM Yeah it seems to do what I want it to do. I'm just seeing if it fixes my wider issue of parsing the XML fragment.

Comment: @C.Spice I think you should've been asking about that in first place.

Comment: @SeM The issue with your solution is that the double double quotes becomes double single quotes. I guess I need to look for the pattern of double double quotes then replace that with a single quote?

Comment: _"So my namespace will look like: 'sbr.gov.au/comn/event.02.data';"_ No, it will look like in your comment.

Comment: @SeM Sorry I'm not sure I follow. Apologies if I'm making this harder than it should be.

Answer (score 2):

when use @ before a string, you must type "" as ".
At the end, ns contins

```
<tns:Event xmlns:tns="http://sbr.gov.au/comn/event.02.data">
```

or you can do this:

```
string ns = "<tns:Event xmlns:tns=\"http://sbr.gov.au/comn/event.02.data\">";
```

but no different

Comment: I believe single quote is `'` symbol.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace "" with \' for single quote

```
 Regex.Replace(ns, @"""", "\'");
```

or replace "" with \" for double quote

```
Regex.Replace(ns, @"""", "\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string's `Replace()` method:

```
ns = ns.Replace('"', '\'');
```

or

```
ns = ns.Replace("\"", "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a regex. Something like

```
var checkDoubleQuotes = @"""";
ns = Regex.Replace(ns, checkDoubleQuotes, "\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an escape character for the quote. See this mdn article:
[Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)